# Convert pom file to gradle

Tags: maven, gradle

I am trying to convert a maven build to gradle. I used gradle init to generate the build.gradle file. But, plugins are not resolved properly. Is there any additional setting to be set?

pom file,
https://github.com/bkielczewski/example-spring-mvc-initializer/blob/master/pom.xml

generated file

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'

group = 'eu.kielczewski.example.spring'
version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

description = """Spring MVC Initializer Example"""

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7

repositories {
     maven { url "http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2" }
}
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-webmvc', version:'4.0.2.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version:'3.0.1'
}
```

Mainly I want to migrate maven-war-plugin configurations to gradle.

Answer (score 2):

`gradle init` gives a good head start, but can only do so much. Whatever is left needs to be done manually.

Comment: Thanks. How can I migrate maven-war-plugin configurations to gradle?

Comment: See the "War plugin" chapter in the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html), and the corresponding samples in the *gradle-all* distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Gradle guide clearly explains the usage of "War plugin". Link is http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#war_plugin

In case you want to know all the configurations properties supported by this "war plugin" then refer to 
http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.War.html

However, As per your pom I think you are more interested in knowing how to set the "failOnMissingWebXml" configuration when you saying that "Mainly I want to migrate maven-war-plugin configurations to gradle." There is no property with the exact name in gradle but you can do this with "webXml" property in gradle war plugin as its definition says "The web.xml file to include in the WAR archive. When null, no web.xml file is included in the WAR.".

HTH...